# Loading image data from pandas to pytorch

Tags: python, pandas, deep-learning, pytorch

I am completely new to pytorch and have previously worked on keras and fastai.
Currently trying an image regression task and the challenge is I have to load the data from pandas dataframe.
Data frame structure:

```
ID   Path   Score
fig1  /folder/fig1.jpg  2
fig2  /folder/fig2.jpg  3
.....
```

I have previously worked on loading images to pytorch directly from folders because it was a simple classification task but kind of stuck now.

I looked into pytorch forums but didn't quiet understand how to implement.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Datasets

You have to use `torch.utils.data.Dataset` structure to define it.
Here is how you can do it in plain `pytorch` (I'm using `pillow` to load the images and `torchvision` to transform them to `torch.Tensor` objects):

```
import torch
import torchvision
from PIL import Image


class MyDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self.dataframe = dataframe

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataframe)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        row = self.dataframe.iloc[index]
        return (
            torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor(Image.open(row["Path"])),
            row["Score"],
        )

dataset = MyDataset(dataframe)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`torchdata`](https://github.com/szymonmaszke/torchdata) (**disclaimer: shameless self-promotion as I'm the author...**) which allows you to decouple `Path` and `Scores` like this:

```
import torchvision
from PIL import Image

import torchdata


class ImageDataset(torchdata.datasets.FilesDataset):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return Image.open(self.files[index])


class Labels(torchdata.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, scores):
        super().__init__()
        self.scores = scores

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.scores)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.scores[index]

# to_numpy for convenience
# I assume all your images are in /folder and have *.jpg extension
dataset = ImageDataset.from_folder("/folder", regex="*.jpg").map(
    torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
) | Labels(dataframe["Score"].to_numpy())
```

(or you could implement it just like in regular `pytorch` but inheriting from `torchdata.Dataset` and calling `super().__init__()` in the constructor).

`torchdata` allows you to cache your images easily or apply some other transformations via `.map` as shown there, [check github repository for more info](https://github.com/szymonmaszke/torchdata) or ask in the comment.

### DataLoader

Either way you choose you should wrap your dataset in `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` to create batches and iterate over them, like this:

```
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

for images, scores in dataloader:
    # Rest of your code to train neural network or smth
    ...
```

Do with those images and scores what you want in the loop.